# Find if date is present in Range of cells (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, find

I have a cell `F2` that contains a Date, and is formatted as Custom Date field displaying only day and month.

Then i have a Range of Cells `C3;C60` that contains also Dates and is formatted as European Date field displaying `dd/mm/yyyy`

I am writing a VBA that makes a check on those fields, but it is not working.
in the sample below the variable `c` can be any cell between `F5` and `F20`.

I get `RuntimeError 91.`

```
If Worksheets(1).Range("C3", "C60").Find(Worksheets(1).Cells(2, c.Column).Value) = True Then
        c.Value = "Whatever"        
Else
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Find()` returns a range, your if statement is checking to see if it's `TRUE`. That will fail.

```
Dim rng as Range

Set rng = Worksheets(1).Range("C3:C60").Find(Worksheets(1).Cells(2, c.Column).Value)
if not rng is Nothing then
  c.Value = "Whatever"        
Else
```

*Note the inclusion of [Gary's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30509037/2344413) answer*

Comment: Glad that helped. `.Find()` is a wonderful tool, but it comes with some "gotchas". Read up on it and you'll discover it's very useful, jump in blindly and you'll not enjoy yourself...

Answer (score 2):

Substitute:

```
Range("C3:C60")
```

for

```
Range("C3", "C60")
```

There may be other problems.

Comment: @sharkyenergy  See **FreeMan**'s post